# Checking first two characters of a string are A-Z letters

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column in my table which contains car license numbers (which are not validated in any way in the source data).

For the license number to be valid, the first two characters have to be uppercase letters (A-Z).

I've tried adding the following to the WHERE clause:

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(auto.license, 1, 2), '[A-Z]')
```

...but I still get invalid combinations in the output dataset.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(auto.license, 1, 2), '[A-Z]')
```

only checks that there is one A-Z in the first two characters, not that both are.

You don't need the extra substring step, you can do:

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE(auto.license, '^[A-Z]{2}')
```

The caret `^` anchors to the start of the string, and the `{2}` matches the previous pattern twice. If you wanted to match uppercase characters in languages (or character sets?) other than English, which have a different ranges for uppercase and don't just cover the ASCII range A-Z, you could use:

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE(auto.license, '^[[:upper:]]{2}')
```

[Read more about Oracle's regular expression support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020), and [multilingual support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#i1008619).

Comment: I did some testing http://rextester.com/AGKQ80549, but here the query return `Ab`, do you know why? Also is there a difference between '`[A-Z]{2}'` and `'[A-Z][A-Z]'`?

Comment: Looks like the correct answer should be `'^[[:upper:]]{2}')`, the weird part is `[a-z]` work as case insensitve. http://rextester.com/VLULS42459

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I mentioned using `:upper:` for other (than English, which I didn't specify!) languages. That site defaults to German. See http://rextester.com/IZF22733. (Also, no, no real difference between `[A-Z]{2}` and `[A-Z][A-Z]`, just avoids repeating the pattern - makes more difference with higher numbers of course)

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(auto.license, 1, 2), '[A-Z][A-Z]')
```